# Nextjs Incremental Static Regeneration does't seem to work on new blogs, edits

Tags: next.js

I am using ISR but adding new blogs, editing doesn't seem to be working on the production.

```js
// /blogs/[slug].js

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await api.get(`/api/v1/blogs/${params.slug}`);
  const blog = res.data;
  return { props: { blog }, revalidate: 60 };
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await api.get("/api/v1/blogs");
  const blogs = res.data;
  const paths = blogs.map((item) => ({
    params: { slug: item.slug },
  }));
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set your `fallback` value to either `true` or `'blocking'` so that new pages can be generated. Otherwise, paths that don't exist at build time will simply 404.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    // Existing code

    return { paths, fallback: true };
}
```